# Magento 2.3 - Fixing "Cannot redeclare __()" error

Tags: magento2.3, cli, magento-upgrade

Getting error **PHP Fatal error**:

> Cannot redeclare **() (previously declared in
>   /vendor/magento/framework/Phrase/**.php:15) in app/functions.php on
>   line 22

This error is coming while running Magento CLI commands in Magento 2.3 with PHP 7.2.16.

Comment: what commands are you using to change php version?

Comment: rollback recent changes and see what happns.